# Access host IP inside docker container using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to start couple of services inside docker container. Some of the other services like the mongodb is running on the host's machine and not inside docker container. I need to connect with mongodb from inside the docker container.

How can I achieve this using docker-compose ?

Comment: can you elaborate? Add your .yml files at least

Comment: I have a very simple compose file Here is the yml file with only one service running inside it. That service needs to access the mongodb server hosted on a different server. 

`version: '2'
services:

  user-management-service:
    image: user-management-service
    container_name: userManagement
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
 
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing there's a way to achieve this but this is a really bad practice. You want to isolate your host from your containers. The containers cannot access the host by design, and you should not go around this.

The best practice would be a mongodb container running on the same host of your app container, linking them together so they can communicate with each other.

Comment: In some cases, I might not have access to the database directly. It might be installed on client machine and I will only have read access.

Comment: I don't see how that changes what I wrote. Co tenancy of your app and db is also a bad practice (if understand the case you described correctly)

Comment: What I mean to say is that since the database ( mongodb ) is managed by the clients, they are not running inside any container ( docker ). They are directly running on the host machine and I will have to connect with it using the public ip.

Comment: Whether the database is running on docker or not should not concern you, your containers have no problem sending requests out, they only need special configuration to receive requests. As long as you can access the db via a specific ip and port, you should be fine.

Comment: Ok. Let me give another try. Thank you so much for your help. Will keep you posted on this.

Comment: You're welcome. Would appreciate it if you can check the answer as correct if you find it helpful.

Comment: What about giving a container access to the docker service on the host (if it needs to start its own containers)

Comment: That could be achieved by adding the following flag to your `docker run` command - `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a docker container for exactly that use-case https://github.com/qoomon/docker-host

You will be able to access host system by the container dns name e.g. `curl http://dockerhost:8080`